# React Native Scroll View is lagging in iOS and Android for a custom bottom sheet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

https://gist.github.com/shubh007-dev/f86814b5efe379f2529c37596139733b

The above link is to my code in which I've made a Custom Bottom Sheet. I've also added a scrollable view inside the bottom sheet.

**Scenario:**

First problem:

When my bottom sheet is pulled up and reaches it's top position, I'm easily able to drag up my scroll view and not able to reach the end of the view. The end of the view in my case is the `Text` *eu efficitur mattis*.

Second problem:

When my bottom sheet is pulled up and reaches it's top position, and now when I drag down to go at the top of `ScrollView`, the scroll lags and is dragged down sometimes. Also, I'm able to drag down easily **only** when I drag up a bit and then can drag down.

I tried these cases in iPhoneX simulator and an MI device. The issue is same. Can someone please tell how can I get smooth scrolling in this bottom sheet.

PS: I don't want to use a library. I only want to be able to improve my component. 
Thank you

Comment: Please ask two different question in two different post so you can easily get answers. Having two questions in one makes it hard to respond to

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer the answer to your problems, but it sounds like you want debug the performance of your app for problem #2.

Read on that topic:

https://medium.com/@adamjacobb/react-native-performance-profiling-32dd00b93351,

https://matwrites.com/measuring-performance-and-debugging-react-native-apps-part-i/